# PHPExcel date required dd/MM/yy

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, date-formatting

I am using PHPExcel Lib to download excel sheet and  have required the  column date format like 25-May-17 instead of 25-05-17 in my download excel sheet.

I was able to added number format 25-05-17 but not like 25-May-17 and below is my code like.

```
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('V'.$i)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY
    );
```

I can not find the constant in Lib class

```
const FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2 = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
const FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD = 'yy-mm-dd';
const FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY = 'dd/mm/yy';
const FORMAT_DATE_DMYSLASH = 'd/m/y';
const FORMAT_DATE_DMYMINUS = 'd-m-y';
```

Can some please help me on this to set date like d-M-yy(25-May-17)?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not constrained by the predefined constants; those are just some of the format strings that MS Excel recognises... a comprehensive list of ever possible mask would be excessive.... and unnecessary... all you're doing is passing a string value to the `setFormatCode()` method, so you can pass a string literal.

The MS Excel mask for the format that you want is `dd-mmm-yyyy`, and you can set that simply as a string literal rather than using any constant:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('V'.$i)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('dd-mmm-yyyy');
```

Note that MS Excel itself has a "custom" option for number format codes, which allows you to set a string literal in exactly the same way

Comment: Thank you Mark , You Saved my time

Comment: Hey Mark, I was able added in my cell value like 25 Apr 17 but dash(-) is missed, can you please tell me how to keep - instead of space

Comment: It should show a dash exactly as I've shown; but you could always try escaping it with a `\\`

Comment: Hey Mark exactly dash is coming , I was mistaking dd-mmm-yy instead of d-mmm-yy. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MarkBaker How i set formate all cells for a column without loop

Comment: @SuryaprakashPatel - specify a range of cells: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('V1:V255')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('dd-mmm-yyyy');`

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/__filesource/fsource_PHPExcel_Style__PHPExcelStyleNumberFormat.php.html#a56) shows:

```
const FORMAT_DATE_DMYMINUS                = 'd-M-Y';
```

`M` is *A short textual representation of a month, three letters    Jan through Dec*, but with `Y` you'll still get a 4 digit year.

Why not just pass your format `d-M-y`?

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('V'.$i)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('d-M-y');
```

Comment: Hey Abra, I had passed d-M-y but it return like 25-05-y so that was my problem. I do not know why its return like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your desired format directly in your code instead of using one of the predefined formats accessible with PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat's constants.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('V'.$i)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);
```

would become:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('V'.$i)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('d-M-yy');
```

Note that you might want to check and set your locale properly so that the "M" in your format gives you english month names.